# How to add browser-specific favicons?

Tags: browser, favicon

I am trying to implement a favicon on my site. I found that Google Chrome does not work with animated favicons but I would still like to allow animated favicons using other browsers. Is there any way that I could make a favicon specific to Google Chrome and use the animated one on other browsers that support it?

Comment: This is not RoR specific. You can find more information on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32105662/how-to-animate-chrome-and-ie-favicon-a-loading-indicator).

Comment: @Jeremie Yep I had suggested an edit to correct that issue and it's just been approved so the question should be a bit more useful now.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a RoR issue, but I would recommend looking at the following:
http://realfavicongenerator.net/ and the gem https://github.com/RealFaviconGenerator/rails_real_favicon

Old school approach would be: https://rubyplus.com/articles/1751-How-to-Add-Favicon-to-Rails-4-2-App-in-5-minutes, or if you prefer using the favicon link from Rails: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/favicon_link_tag with couple of StackOverflow articles such as this one [Adding icon to rails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130593/adding-icon-to-rails-application)