# Switch statement not working within JSX (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make my switch work within JSX, but for some reason it doesn't work.
Every output has an ID, which is I. Now I am trying to make a switch statement with I, but it will always return the default value.

Why?

My code:

```
 {(() => {
   switch (i) {
     case "0":   return "{indents}";
     case "1":   return "{indents2}";
     case "2":   return "{indents3}";
     default:    return "{indents3}";
   }
  })()}
```

This is all within a div with attribute key={i}.

Comment: What is `i`? Is it actually a string?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes. It is the identifier for the div and it's content. I have a script that will run 3 or more animations in div's, but I need them all to be different. That's why idents, idents2 etc. Now depending on the i, it should run a different animation. That's why the switch.

Comment: It should be case 0, case 1 and case 2.

Comment: @vijayst It is right now? In case of I being 0, it runs indents, in case of I being 1, it runs idents2 etc.

Comment: You should add `console.log(i)` and `console.log(typeof i)` in your IIFE just before your switch statement. That'll give you a clear indication as to why your switch statement is not working. `i` is either not of type string or it's not "0", "1" or "2".

Comment: Double check your data. Your `switch` is fine. I'm betting that `i` is actually a number, or something else entirely.

Comment: @JakeMiller It logs the following: 0 number 1 number.

Comment: @JakeMiller Well, there's your problem. If `i` is a number, the switch needs to use numbers.

Comment: if you were unsure about the variable type and want to allow either, you could case for both `case 0: case "0": //logic break;`. If a case is matched, it will continue to flow through the switch statement until it is broken with `break;` or something is returned with `return`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend maps instead. Maps/objects are type insensitive. It will also reduce execution complexity:

```
const map = {
  0: indents,
  1: indents2,
  2: indents3
}

<div>{map[i] || indents3}</div>
```

Alternatively, since you are using 0,1,2.., you can also have it as an array.

```
const map = [indents, indents2, indents3];
<div>{map[i] || indents3}</div>
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate switch is not O(1) it is as equivalent to nested if else, but mapping is faster as you are trying to access a value directly instead on comparing all the time.

Comment: Will try this out, may I ask why the || indents3?

Comment: thats the fallback default that you have in the switch in OP

Comment: Ah, right, okay, will try this now. Why is does it reduce execution complexity though?

Comment: javascript objects act like hashes and have direct access to values. But switch statements depend on the implementation of the browser, the browser can make it a linear complexity or make it n comparisons. Try [switch complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41109196) and [object complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241676) for more info on the topic